# Modern proof of a theorem of Dickson on finite representation type

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers

In Theorem 3.1 the paper S. Dickson, *On algebras of finite representation type*
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 135 (1969), 127-141, Dickson gives a sufficient condition for an algebra to have infinite representation type.  This work was done in the days before Auslander-Reiten theory and I'm wondering if anybody knows a proof, or a reference to a proof, using standard facts about Ausland-Reiten quivers of algebras of finite representation type (like, for instance, that they don't have multiple edges).

Dickson doesn't necessarily work over an algebraically closed field.  If it simplifies the answer, I'm willing to assume this, but I'm also ok with valuated AR quivers being used in the answer.

Here is the version of Thm 3.1 I'm interested in:

> Thm(Dickson): Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$.  Assume there is a finite dimensional indecomposable module $M$ with  isomorphic indecomposable submodules $C,C'$ with $C\cap C'=0$ such that $\mathrm{Ext}^1_A(M,C)=0$ and, for every endomorphism $\psi$ of $M$, $\psi(C)\cap \psi(C')=0$ and if $\psi$ is nilpotent, then $\psi(C)=0=\psi(C')$.  Then $A$ has infinite representation type.

Comment: Isn't this just a question of embedding the representation theory of the Kronecker quiver?

Comment: @DaveBenson, I guess it depends on what you mean by that.  It doesn't literally embed the quiver but it might be close to that.  An example that meets this is take a quiver with vertices v,w edges a:v->w and b:w->v and loop g at v with ba=0, bg=0, ga=0, g^2=0.  The projective indecomposable at v has two copies of the simple for v in its socle meeting this criterion.  In what sense does the rep theory of the Kronecker quiver embed?  This is a string algebra of infinite representation type.

Comment: There's a map from the quiver algebra of the Kronecker quiver to the endomorphism algebra of $P_v \oplus v$ that makes the latter into a bimodule for the Kronecker quiver algebra and your quiver algebra. Tensoring with this bimodule gives a functor from Kronecker modules to modules for your quiver that sends indecomposable modules to indecomposable modules. I think you can imagine what the image of a string module looks like.

Comment: @DaveBenson, does this with in the general case with $M\oplus C$? I can see you can map in the kronecker quiver to the endomorphism rings by sending the the first vertex to the projection to C and the second to the projection to M and then the two arrows map to the two inclusions.  How do I know tensoring with this bimodule reflects isomorphism for indecomposables and preserves indecomposables? Presumably the hypotheses guarantee this?

Comment: Yes, and that's where the work lies. But I think this is pretty much what Dickson is doing.

Comment: @DaveBenson.       Ok, I see.  That at least gives me an idea of what is going on. In my case of interest M is projective if that simplifies things